# AUTHID DEFINER param does not work

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure created on USER A schema with the AUTHID DEFINER param. This procedure creates some tables if it does not exists, an later it does insert operations in all tables.

This param works correctly in the insert operation, but not in the create table operation. I call the procedure from another user called USER B, so the param theorically should allow the USER B execute the procedure as USER A and create the tables in USER A schema and later insert all data.

Anyone knows why the procedure returns an insufficient privileges error when I call it? I tried to execute the "create table" statement directly in USER A schema and it works...

Thanks.

Comment: How is the privilege applied? By a role (e.g. role DBA)? It must be granted explicitly like `GRANT CREATE TABLE TO USER_A;`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean, but when I execute "select * from session_privs;" the user B only have CREATE SESSION AND SYNONYM privileges. On the other hand USER_A also have CREATE TABLE privilege and others...

Comment: Did you `GRANT EXECUTE ON procedure_XY TO USER_B;`?

Comment: Yes, USER_B also have the execution grant.

Comment: Double-check by querying `user_sys_privs` as USER_A.

Comment: If i query this `select * from user_sys_privs` this returns no rows

Answer (score 0):

USER A probably has the RESOURCE role granted, which enables you to create tables manually - that is why you are able to 'execute the "create table" statement directly in USER A schema'.

But when executing PL/SQL code, different privileges apply, since **roles are disabled in procedures**, see [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authorization.htm#i1007304).

So, you need to explicitly grant the CREATE TABLE privilege to USER A.